# Generating object structure from SOAP WSDL

Tags: node.js, soap, wsdl

I need to call a SOAP service and I'm having trouble comming up with the correct input parameters for a call. I inspect the WSDL and it seems - to me - like the nesting for the input goes deep (looks like I have to send a very complex data structure to get a result).

I was thinking, isn't there a program or a way i can have the WSDL parsed and display the object structure? It's for a nodejs project, so i can't just import the WSDL and have Java generate the objects. If i could somehow get type completion in my editor VSC, that would be great, but i just need some way to display the hieraki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would importing the WSDL into a testing tool like soapUI get you what you are looking for? You could then see the structure of all of the requests expected by the web service endpoint.

Comment: Yes, this is actually what i ended up doing. SoapUI would keep crashing on me though, until i de-selected the option to generate sample requests. I went and manually generated sample request for the method i had to call and i basically got what i needed :)